# Five words. Four Wikipedia pages. One rebus

Tags: rebus

As the title suggests, the accepted answer will explain how each word was found and link the four relevant [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/) pages. Some parts are definitely harder than others, but once several words are found, the rest will fall into place. Happy solving!

---

[image: A rebus containing five words]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Image shows **Alexander** (the Great).
2. Cardinals are above bishops. The **Pope** is above the cardinals.
3. Splitting "bed" and "cent" according to the image makes the word **Benedict**.
4. "Tavern"-"vet"+"~kobold"-"cob" makes **Arnold**.
5. "Black" in German is "schwarz" and "harrow" in German is "egge". Putting them together makes **Schwarzenegger**.

Taking them in pairs:

- [Alexander Pope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Pope)
- [Pope Benedict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pope_Benedict)
- [Benedict Arnold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict_Arnold)
- [Arnold Schwarzenegger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnold_Schwarzenegger)

Comment: Sounds like a rebus version of chain reaction!